# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/netty/shaded/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$1 in using DialogFlow Java Client

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I am running a Springboot Application to use DialogFlow Java Client. I am running this on JBoss server and am deploying it as a war file. Each time, I try to re-deploy the war file or sometimes when I stop the JBoss server I get this exception

```
 Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder$2@56773d85: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/netty/shaded/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$1
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:498)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.ensureThreadStarted(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:964)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.shutdownGracefully(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:663)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.shutdownGracefully(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils$DefaultEventLoopGroupResource.close(Utils.java:431)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils$DefaultEventLoopGroupResource.close(Utils.java:394)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder$2.run(SharedResourceHolder.java:139)
    at io.grpc.internal.LogExceptionRunnable.run(LogExceptionRunnable.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1 from [Module "deployment.smartchat.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Snippet of my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>12.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Sounds like your jar file did not include all the compiled classes.

Comment: The war file does contain grpc-netty-shaded-1.32.1.jar
Also this exception occurs only when I re-deploy the war file or intermittently when I stop the JBOSS server. Otherwise the application works fine.

Comment: I have the same issue. did you get the solution @user14481234